# How do i keep my responsive design with and without a sidebar?

Tags: html, css

I have decided to add a sidebar to the left side of all my pages in my website. The sidebar can either be concealed or visible, I do not want it to overlap the existing page.

If I were to have a sidebar as such, the content of the page tends to overflow with the container. I need the content to change  according to its container width rather than the browser width.

I do not want to create a container for the content and set `overflow-y` to `auto` and make it stretch to browser height as I would need to do this for all my pages...

I have already tried changing the left margin on the body and adding a div with `position: fixed` as a sidebar.

How would I go about changing the content according to its container width rather than the browser width?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the approach below:

```
#content {
width: 80%; /* Adjust as need */
position: relative;
}

#content .children {
max-width: 100%; /* Or less, to keep the children from overflowing */
}
```

Note: I used imaginary ID and Class

Comment: this still causes font sizes (for example) to change size too late. Let's say i've set the font size to change when the screen width is 720px wide. i want this to happen when the content container is 720px instead. Now it would change when the container is 500 pixels wide.